# v-model not updating when element loses focus?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I'm running into an issue with Vue where a v-model on a custom input is not updating when the element loses focus.

For example, if I have two of these custom input elements, and I type a value into the first one, and quickly tab into the second one, it will truncate the value from the first one by one or two characters.

Here is the custom form element's HTML and the method that is called on keyup:

```
<input type="string" ref="input"
  v-on:keyup="checkInput"
  v-on:focus="hasFocus"
  v-on:focusout="lostFocus">

checkInput(event){
        console.log("Checking input for " + this.title);
        // If keycode is 9 (tab), ignore. Don't raise errors or emit values if user is just tabbing into field
        if(event.keyCode !== 9){
          var text = this.$refs.input.value;
          this.check = this.regex.test(text);
          this.$emit('input', text);
          this.$emit('check', this.check);
          console.log("Emit: " + text);
          this.hasFocus();
        }
      },
```

And here's how it's initialized in the template

```
<CustomFormElement:title="'Name'" :valid="'^(?!\\s*$).+'"
                  :errorMessage="'Name cannot be blank'"
                  v-model="data.name"
                  @check="(value) => formCheck('name', value)"
                  class="form_field"
      ></CustomFormElement>
```

When I go to checkInput and print out what text is being emitted, it truncates the value by a few characters if I type quickly and tab to the next input. For example, if I type "John Smith", data.name will equal "John Smi".

Is there any reason why v-on:keyup stops firing after the element loses focus. Any reason why the v-model is not updating after the element loses focus?

Comment: Somethings look off in the custom form element. 1) There is no space before `:title` after the opening tag. 2) There is a colon (`:`) around `title` and `errorMessage` but appears to be only Strings. 3) `errorMessage` should be `error-message` to encourage kabob-case in HTML.

Comment: 1. That was a typo from pasting into StackOverflow, 2. Fixed, 3. Fixed. Issue still persists unfortunately

Comment: You don't need to use `ref`, you already have the value at `event.target.value` and keyup will not fire if you press a key and then hit another key before releasing the first key.  Easy test is to press any letter and while holding it press the tab key.  The keyup event will not fire.

Comment: So how would I fix this problem? Whether I use the emitted keyup event or v-model, it will truncate the last characters when typing quickly.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish but I don't see why @input wouldn't work for you.  There's no reason to check for the tab key as it won't register with `@input`.

Comment: If I have two <CustomFormElements>, with the v-model bound to the first one being "data.first" and the v-model bound to the second being "data.second", and I type "John Smith" into the first form element, and as soon as I'm done typing, tab into the second element, the value of data.first will equal "John Smi". It doesn't accept the last few characters when quickly tabbing through the form elements.